# VPS OS Debian 6 : How to Setting Up db. Bind9 for Multiple IPs (Beginner)

Tags: linux, debian, vps, bind9

My server IP is : **103.11.xx.xxx**

I followed setting up my VPS from [here](http://hubpages.com/technology/Configure-Apache2-VirtualHost-and-Bind9-on-Debian)

and, I had to copy and edit ***etc/bind/db.local*** to ***etc/bind/db.mywebsite***:

```
; BIND data file for mywebsite.com 
; 
$ORIGIN mywebsite.com. 
$TTL    604800 
@   IN  SOA     ns1.mywebsite.com. myemail.mywebsite.com. (  
            2009120101 ; Serial 
            604800 ; Refresh 
            86400 ; Retry 
            2419200 ; Expire 
            604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL 
;  

    IN  NS  ns1.mywebsite.com. 
    IN  NS  ns2.mywebsite.com.
    IN  MX 10   mail.mywebsite.com.

localhost       IN  A       127.0.0.1
mywebsite.com.  IN  A       123.45.67.91
ns1             IN  A       123.45.67.89
ns2             IN  A       123.45.67.90

www             IN  A       123.45.67.91
ftp             IN  A       123.45.67.91
mail            IN  A       123.45.67.92

boards          IN  CNAME   www
```

my questions is:

1. how do i get IP 123.45.67.89, 123.45.67.90, 123.45.67.91 and 123.45.67.92. Which is part of the IP of my server IP (103.11.xx.xxx). 
   how about another IPs, do i have to generate a new ip on the server? and what are the benefits of many ip like this?
2. how about 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa if I used IP 103.11.xx.xxx?
3. what is the meaning '***myemail***' in ns1.mywebsite.com. myemail.mywebsite.com. whether the user like '***root***' etc?

As a beginner, I very confused and many..many.. thank you in advance for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If i got it right and you don't have another IPs except `103.11.xx.xxx`, you have to request your hosting-provider in order to get new IPs. It's good to have more than just one IP in case of DDOS on your server (especially, when second IP routed through network with anti-DDOS configuration) or blacklisting of your IP. That's not the only reasons to have more than one IP, but for me they are the must important.
2. `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa` - this is a reverse DNS zone, which is responsible for answers to reverse DNS requests, for example, when some SMTP server receiving mail from your MTA, it checking out if your IP matches your domain name, and if it doesn't, it could reject your mail. In other words, regular DNS request trying to match a pair `domain name:IP` and reverse - `IP:domain name`.
3. `myemail.mywebsite.com.` - this is an email address of a person, who's responsible for that particular DNS-server or DNS-zone. In our case, that's you, my friend. )

Comment: thanks for your answers. Now, I have some idea about the things mentioned above. However, for 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa whether I should write xx.11.103.in-addr.arpa (of course xx are numeric) if my server IP is 103.11.xx.xxx? or how do I find a subnet for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a new reverse zone file called xxx.xx.11.103.in-addr.arpa and configure it. Here's guide that would help you with configuration: http://www.philchen.com/2007/04/04/configuring-reverse-dns

Comment: OK, I will try it.. you're very helpul. thanks so much,, :-)

Comment: You are welcome, my dawg. :)